# Google Identity Toolkit on Android: Facebook user switch

Tags: android, facebook, google-identity-toolkit

I am having problem with facebook plugin. As soon as I log into facebook with some account, there is no way to switch to another facebook account.

In case of google, there is an account switching popup window, which allows switch to a different user.

I have tried facebook plugin ver3 and ver4. I also downloaded the example gitkitmobile app from Google Play. And the behavior is consistent in all of these cases. Is this a bug? And if so, how can I overcome this?

Sincerely,
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Facebook Android SDK does not support account selection or switch, and there is not much Google Identity Toolkit could do to change the behavior of Facebook SDK.

If you log out of the Facebook app on the device, you should be able to type a different email when signing with Facebook.

Comment: this behavior is not linked to the fb app. I can delete the app, or logout there, and it does not affect the behavior. The app is configured not to use SSO, so it is possible. When I was using facebook SDK directly, I had no problem to log in using a different user. It is a GIT implementation issue